# How to specify two types in php?

Tags: php, oop

I have a base class:

```
class DataModel implements IModel
{
}
```

And child class:

```
class DataModelDoctor extends DataModel
{

}
```

In constructor of another class I set type of incoming parameter as `DataModel`:

```
public function __construct(DataModel $model)
{}
```

When I create instance of class I pass an instance of `DataModelDoctor()`.

It invokes an error, because expects `DataModel`.

Therefore question, why it is not compatible `DataModelDoctor` extends`DataModel`?

Is it possible to set like:

```
public function __construct(DataModel | DataModelDoctor $model) {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work as long as PHP can find that `DataModelDoctor` class indeed extends from `DataModel` class.

You need to make sure that, if they use different namespaces, you need to explicitly declare complete class name including its namespace. For example

```
<?php

namespace Some\Other\Namespace2;

use Some\Other\Namespace1\DataModel;

class DataModelDoctor extends DataModel
{
}
```

In above example, `DataModel` and `DataModelDoctor` are on different namespaces. If you remove `use` clause on above code, `DataModel` will be assumed has same namespace as `DataModelDoctor` class.

In other class that you need `DataModel` instance, if they belong to different namespaces, then you need to specify namespace.

```
use Some\Other\Namespace1\DataModel;
...

public function __construct(DataModel $model)
{
}
```

Better approach is to declare with `IModel` interface.

```
public function __construct(IModel $model)  
{
    $this->model = $model;
}
```

Then you can pass any classes which implements `IModel`.

Comment: If `DataModel`  implements `IModel` is it enough to set like you offer if I pass `new DataModelDoctor()`?

Comment: Yes. But really your code should work with the base class. Can you provide the error you're getting?

Comment: @Karabah as Antony said, your code should work. I update my answer with explanation on namespace.